# Unable to connect WiFi to the Pi

Tags: wifi, networking

My new raspberry pi is unable to connect to the internet. I got a dongle provided from with the pi itself so it should not have any compatibility issues. The network icon shows 'wlan0: Not associated' when I try to connect. I followed some posts on the internet and went to nano /etc/network/interfaces
and changed it to

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
       wireless-essid "WiFiName"
       wireless-key "password"

according to one of the post said. I don't have a password so I left that part "". Still I am unable to connect. Please help!!

Answer (score 3):

This often happens if the power supply to the RPi is not powerful enough.

A standard 0.5Amp USB is not enough to drive a Pi with a Wifi dongle.

My tip, make sure you get a sufficiently powerful power-supply for the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't fiddle with the files it may work. Put them back the way they were.
The following shows the correct file contents (as well as how to setup).

[How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip/37921#37921)

NOTE If you don't know the password you won't be able to setup.